# Batch - trying to obtain the detail of systeminfo.exe

Tags: batch-file, powershell, filesysteminfo

Like the results of this..

SYSTEMINFO >> RESULTS.TXT

Systeminfo | find "Network Card"

However, this only captures the first line entry:

```
Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
```

What I would really like to see is:

```
Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Production
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 1.1.1.1
                           [02]: VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Backup
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 2.2.2.2
```

without having to run the whole systeminfo - can I capture the detail about the Network cards.

Did also try to push this through PowerShell..

```
& systeminfo.exe | & FIND.exe "Network Card"
```

And is not working either..  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, like it does for me, `Network Card(s):` always comes up last in the output of `systeminfo`, then the following should work for you.

```
@echo off
set s=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('systeminfo') do (
    if defined s echo %%a
    for /f %%b in ("%%a") do if "%%b"=="Network" echo %%a & set s=1
)
```

Sets `s` as a switch when it reaches `Network Card(s)` and outputs everything from there.

*IF* the `Network Card(s)` section doesn't come up last, and you require a more definitive method of getting the network card information, AND you are okay with the CSV formatted output, then this should also work (albeit possibly over complicated):

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('systeminfo /FO CSV') do (
    set line=%%a
    set line=!line:,= !
    if "!c!"=="0" for %%b in (!line!) do (
        set /a c+=1
        if "%%~b"=="Network Card(s)" echo %%~b
    ) else for %%c in (!line!) do (
        set /a c-=1
        if "!c!"=="0" echo %%~c
    )
)
```

Comment: This is awesome!!  I love it and works great..  I was really trying to get away from using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Well, even though I just read in one of the comments you were trying to get away from PowerShell, since I got it working, and it dumps all the info your example had, I figured I'd post it anyway... :)

```
function Get-NetworkCards {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$ComputerName = "LocalHost"
)
    $adapterCfg = ( gwmi -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName | Sort-Object Index )

    $adapter = ( gwmi -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName $ComputerName | Sort-Object Index )

    foreach ( $nic in $adapterCfg ) {
        if( $nic.IPEnabled -eq $true ) {
            foreach ( $settings in $adapter ) {
                if( $settings.DeviceID -eq $nic.Index ) {
                    $curr = $settings
                }
            }
            $props = [ordered]@{
                Description = $nic.Description;
                Connection = $curr.NetConnectionID;
                DHCPEnabled = $nic.DHCPEnabled;
                IPAddresses = $nic.IPAddress;
            }

            $Obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $props

            $Obj
        }
    }
}

get-networkcards
```

Comment: I do appreciate your assistance.  I am able to run PowerShell and Batch..  I can run VBS, but has to be codesigned..  Just trying to get away from having to run many technologies..  Thanks again!

Comment: On a side note, yours doesn't actually return everything systeminfo does. SystemInfo kicks back physical adapters. If you replace your entire ForEach loop with this it fixes it: `ForEach($NIC in $adapter){If($NIC.PhysicalAdapter){$Curr = $adapterCfg|?{$_.Index -eq $NIC.DeviceID};[pscustomobject]@{Description = $curr.Description;Connection = $NIC.NetConnectionID;DHCPEnabled = $Curr.DHCPEnabled;IPAddresses = $Curr.IPAddress}}}`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician -- Good point, I missed that little detail... :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, in PowerShell - http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/08/how-do-i-find-information-about-the-network-adapter-cards-on-my-computer.aspx

Quoting their script:

```
Param($computer = "localhost")
function funline ($strIN)
{
 $num = $strIN.length
 for($i=1 ; $i -le $num ; $i++)
  { $funline = $funline + "=" }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow $strIN 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor darkYellow $funline
} #end funline

Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan "Network adapter settings on $computer"
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_NetworkAdapterSetting `
-computername $computer |
Foreach-object `
 {
  If( ([wmi]$_.element).netconnectionstatus -eq 2)
    {
     funline("Adapter: $($_.setting)")
     [wmi]$_.setting
     [wmi]$_.element
    } #end if
 } #end foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

Systeminfo with text-extraction in PowerShell:

```
$sys = systeminfo
$start = ($sys | select-string "network card" -SimpleMatch).LineNumber
$sys[($start-1)..($sys.Length-1)] | Out-File RESULTS.TXT
```

Personally, I would have used a WMI-based solution to get the network information.